# curl to ignore special characters

Tags: curl

I want to use curl for a Post Request. This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) tells how to do it. But what if the content inside a param has charaters like `&`. It disintegrates the text and assumes it as an another attribute. How to deal with such characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can [URL encode](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them.

I have used [Eric Meyer’s page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder) with success. In your case

```
& = %26
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the '&' character... dependant on which language you're coding in, there's always a way.